# downloadURL from storage sequentially - Swift - Programmatically

Tags: swift, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have an array of UIImages:

I load it to Firebase Storage and for each image I download its url: Then I add it to an array like this:

```
var imageUrlStringArray = [String]()
                    
                    //imagesArray is ORDINATED correctly
for i in 0...imagesArray.count-1{
                        
let imageID = "\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
guard let imageData = imagesArray[i].jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4) else { return }
                        
storageThumbnailsRef.child(imageID).putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, err) in
if let err = err{
                                print("impossible to add a thumbnail image: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                                return
                            }
                            
storageThumbnailsRef.child(imageID).downloadURL { (url, err) in
                                if let err = err{
                                    print("impossible to download image: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                                    return
                                }
                                
                    imageUrlStringArray.append(url!.absoluteString)
                            }
                        }
                    }
   firestorePosts.addDocument(data: ["arrayImages": imageUrlStringArray])
```

The initial array `imagesArray` is ordinated correctly as I want to, the other array `imageUrlStringArray` is not ordered as the first one.

I know this is because the function `downloadURL` is asynchronous and so as soon as an imageURL is downloaded it is added to the array.

But how can I still have the `imageUrlStringArray` ordered as `imagesArray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary instead of an array, using the index of the `for` loop to keep the order of the image url strings:

```
var imageUrlStringArray = [Int: String]()
```

Then change:

```
imageUrlStringArray.append(url!.absoluteString)
```

to the following, using `imagesArray` index as the key:

```
imageUrlStringArray.updateValue(url!.absoluteString, forKey: i)
```

Finally when all requests end, you can convert the dictionary back to an array using a simple `map` call, after sorting the array by index:

```
let orderedImageUrlStringArray = imageUrlStringArray.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key }).map(\.value)
```